# How does the CTC loss work?

Tags: reference-request, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-networks, speech-recognition, ctc-loss

I am trying to implement CTC loss in TensorFlow, but [their documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/ctc_loss) is pretty limited. So I am not sure how to approach the problem. I found [a good example in Theano](https://github.com/mohammadpz/CTC-Connectionist-Temporal-Classification/blob/master/ctc_cost.py).

Are any other resources that explain the CTC loss?

I am also trying to understand how its forward-backward algorithm works and what the beam decoder in the case of the CTC loss is.

Answer (score 3):

**Connectionist Temporal Classification (CTC)** can be useful for sequence modeling problems, like **speech recognition** and **handwritten recognition**, where the input and output sequences might have different sizes, so there's **the problem of aligning the sequences**. For instance, in speech recognition, not all sounds in speech correspond to a character, so how do we know if a sound should be converted to one of the possible chars? Moreover, we assume that we don't have a training dataset where the input and output sequences are aligned. The creation/labeling of such a dataset would be quite consuming. That's why CTC was introduced.

So, mathematically, the speech/handwritten recognition task can be written as

$$
Y^* = \text{argmax}_Y p(Y \mid X),
$$
where $Y^* = [y_1, \dots, y_M]$ is the ideal output sequence for $X = [x_1, \dots, x_T]$. Note that $T$ may be different from $M$.

Now, let's say that you have a speech $X = [x_1, \dots, x_N]$ and the output should be the sequence $Y^* = [h, e, l, l, o]$. One naive approach to solve this problem would be, for each input $x_i$, we would predict the most likely char, so we could end up with an output sequence like $\hat{Y} = [h, e, e, l, l, l, o]$ (when $T = 7$ and $M = 5$), then we could remove all duplicates, so we would end up with $\hat{Y}' = [h, e, l, o]$. However, this is not the correct approach, because, as you can see, there are words where the same letter appears twice in a row.

To solve this problem, we can introduce a **special character**, which we can denote by $\epsilon$. So, in this case, the idea is that $\epsilon$ should be predicted around exactly two (and not more or less) "l". Once the sequence is predicted, we can remove $\epsilon$ and, hopefully, we have a valid word, rather than a word like "helo" or "hellllo".

The idea of CTC is, for each $x_i$, the neural network produces a probability distribution over the possible chars, which we can denote by $p_t(a_t \mid X)$. In the example above, a probability distribution over $\{h, e, l, o, \epsilon \}$. So, for example, the probability vector for $x_1$ could be $p_1(a_1 \mid X) = [0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]$. Given all probability vectors $p_t(a_t \mid X)$, for $t=1, \dots, T$, we can compute the probability of an alignment (a specific output sequence). Then we [marginalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) over the set of alignments.

To reflect these ideas, the **CTC loss function** is defined as follows

$$
p(Y \mid X)=\underbrace{\sum_{A \in \mathcal{A}_{X, Y}} }_{\text{Marginalization}\\\text{over set of}\\ \text{alignments}} \underbrace{\prod_{t=1}^{T} p_{t}\left(a_{t} \mid X\right)}_{\text{Probability}\\\text{for a single}\\\text{alignment}}
$$
We can then use an RNN to model $p_t(a_t \mid X)$ given that [RNNs are good for sequence prediction](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/18199/2444).

Now, another problem is that there can be many alignments, so the computation of the loss may be expensive if done naively. To solve this problem, you can use a **dynamic programming** algorithm, the **CTC forward-backward algorithm**. The details of how this is done, how the **gradient** of the CTC loss is computed, how **inference** is done in this context (including the details of **beam search**), and other details can be found in this nice article [Sequence Modeling With CTC](https://distill.pub/2017/ctc/) (2017) by Awni Hannun, which this answer is based on.

You can also read the original paper [Connectionist Temporal Classification: Labeling Unsegmented Sequence Data with Recurrent Neural Networks](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Egraves/icml_2006.pdf) (2006), by Alex Graves et al., mentioned in the linked [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/ctc_loss), which presents and explains the CTC loss and the CTC forward-backward algorithm (in section 4.1).