# Is a recurrent layer same as LSTM or single-layered LSTM?

Tags: terminology, recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory

In MLP, there are neurons that form a layer. Each hidden layer gives a vector of number that is the output of that layer.

In CNN, there are kernels that form a convolutional layer. Each layer gives feature maps that are the output of that layer.

In LSTM, there are cells that form a recurrent layer. Each layer gives a sequence that is the output of that layer.

This is my understanding of the basic terminology regarding MLP, CNN, and LSTM.

But consider the [following description](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html) regarding the number of layers in LSTM in PyTorch

> num_layers – Number of **recurrent layers**. E.g., setting num_layers=2
> would mean **stacking two LSTMs** together to form a stacked LSTM, with
> the second LSTM taking in outputs of the first LSTM and computing the
> final results. Default: 1

The description uses the "number of recurrent layers" and the "LSTM" in a similar manner. How I can understand this? Is it costmary to consider a recurrent layer as an LSTM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the context, when people use the term *LSTM*, they either refer to

- an **LSTM layer**,
- an **LSTM unit** (like a recurrent unit in an RNN or neuron in an MLP), or
- an **LSTM neural network** (i.e. an RNN that uses LSTM units or layers).

[In TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM), an LSTM is a layer, so you can stack multiple LSTMs to create deeper architectures.

[In PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html), the class `LSTM` can create an LSTM layer or multiple LSTM layers stacked together. You also have an [`LSTMCell`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTMCell.html), which should be just one LSTM layer.

[My answer here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/18199/2444) should also be useful.